# how is the time complexity of this code O(n5)?

Tags: c++

How is the time complexity of this code O(n5)?

```
void function(int n) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++) 
            if (j%i == 0) 
            { 
                for (int k=0; k<j; k++) 
                    printf("*"); 
            } 
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow can't teach you everything about complexities from scratch, so you will have to do at least some research up front. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Why do you think that it should not be `n^5`? If you explain why you think it should be something else, then we can tell you what your false assumption is.

Comment: Your code doesn't use `count`; it could (add `count++` to the body of the inner loop, or replace that `printf()` with `count++`).  You could then print the value of `count` at the end of the function: `printf("f(%d) = %d\n", n, count);` or similar.  If you don't drop the `printf()`, do add the equivalent of `putchar('\n');` at the end of the function.  You can then count number of stars per call.

Comment: Doesn't the code experience a divide by zero error on `j % i` when `i == 0`?

Answer (score 4):

1st `for` loop runs `O(n)` times.

2nd `for` loop runs `O(n*n)` times on each iteration of the 1st loop. Notice it's run up to `i*i`.

3rd `for` loop runs `O(n*n)` times on each iteration of the 2nd loop. Notice it's run up to `j` which has max limit `O(n*n)`.

Overall time complexity is `O(n^5)`. You can dry run with some sample input and figure out the pattern.